# xml-to-json number-formatter entry has no effect

Tags: xpath, saxon, xslt-3.0

When using Saxon 12.1, I tried to use the function `xml-to-json` new options entry `number-formatter`. It appears Saxon recognizes it, but I get no change to my output.

Input XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="repro.xsd">
<OptionPosition>-27975240</OptionPosition>
</root>
```

Input XSLT

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:hr="hr" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xhtml xs err" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <!--<xsl:import-schema schema-location="repro.xsd"/>--> 
    <xsl:function name="hr:really-good" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        1</xsl:function>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="mine">
            <map>
                <array key="AdjudicatorName">                   
                        <number>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/root/OptionPosition"/>
                        </number>           
                </array>                
            </map>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($mine, map{'number-formatter': hr:really-good })" />
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I realize nowhere in the Saxon documentation does it say this is implemented, but it doesn't say it isn't either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick test using this query from the command line:

```
let $x := <fn:number xmlns:fn='http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions'>25</fn:number> 
return xml-to-json($x, map{'number-formatter':function($n){'++++'||$n}})
```

and it produced the output ++++25.

So the feature is working in principle.

There's an obvious error in your code which is that you have set the value of the property to `hr:really-good` rather than `hr:really-good#1`, so it's interpreted as an element name rather than a function reference. But if I try to replicate that I get a clear error message telling me the value must be a function.

(delete): ~~That may be related to another error in your code which is that the XML supplied to the xml-to-json function is in the wrong namespace. But again, I would expect that to result in an error message.~~

Comment: I think the default namespace to put the result elements in the right namespace is in there declared on the root element i.e. `xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example with Mike's suggested fix at the [XML workbench demo](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/index-saxon12api.html?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%20xmlns%3Ahr%3D%22hr%22%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%20xmlns%3Afn%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%20xmlns%3Amath%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmath%22%20xmlns%3Aarray%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Farray%22%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%20xmlns%3Axhtml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%20xmlns%3Aerr%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxqt-errors%22%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22array%20fn%20map%20math%20xhtml%20xs%20err%22%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afunction%20name%3D%22hr%3Areally-good%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22input%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%3C%2Fxsl%3Afunction%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22mine%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22AdjudicatorName%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%2Froot%2FOptionPosition%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fnumber%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22xml-to-json%28%24mine%2C%20map%7B%27number-formatter%27%3A%20hr%3Areally-good%231%20%7D%29%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%20%20%20%20%20%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Croot%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22%20xsi%3AnoNamespaceSchemaLocation%3D%22repro.xsd%22%3E%0A%3COptionPosition%3E-27975240%3C%2FOptionPosition%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML) using Saxon HE 12 and it outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>{"AdjudicatorName":[
        1]}
```